# EBADF using JNI to read/write serial port in Android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, serial-port, java-native-interface

I'm having trouble accessing a serial port under Android.

For that, I programmed a serial library using JNI, with simple functions to open, read and write a serial port.

```
private static class ReturnC{
    public int retcode;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public int errno;
    public String descripcionError;
}


private native ReturnC open_port(String portPath);
private native ReturnC set_speed(int fd, int speed);
...
private native ReturnC read_bytes_in_received_buffer(int fd, int cantidadMaximaALeer, byte[] buffer);
private native ReturnC send_buffer(int fs, byte[] buffer);
private native void close_port(int fd);
```

I get the file descriptor of the open port in the open_port call, and use it to reference the port in the read/write operations.

This works well... for a while. After a garbage collection, any access to the fd returns an EBADF. Sure enough, it's not valid any more. If I reopen it immediately, I can continue to use the port (under another or the same fd number).

So, I guess it's getting closed because of something that happens in the garbage collection. I'm not a Java expert, and especially not JNI expert, coming from a C background. In my world, file descriptors are valid until closed explicitly, or the process exits, and I'm having a hard time tracing the conditions that cause an invalid fd here.

I'm poring over Sheng Liang's JNI guide and specification, it's a bit too overwhelming. Can anybody help?

Comment: If the fd is only known to native code, there is no reason for garbage collection to affect it.  Are you outputting log messages when `close_port()` is called?

Comment: Yes, with the its result. It's never called. 

In fact, I am getting this problem in the middle of a serial dialog - read/writes without problem, then a GC, and BAM - ebadf next time I try to access the fd. 

Right now I'm checking errno, and retrying after reopening  - this works, but it's horribly hackish, and I have to make sure I open the port in exactly the same way and not lose characters in the input queue.

Comment: Hi, could you solve this? If you did, how? Thanks!

Comment: Guillermo, sadly no. I continued to use the errno check/reopen port logic.